# Efficiently blocking function execution while persistent QThread workers complete a round of work

Tags: qt, qthread

My issue is that there doesn’t seem to be an efficient way in Qt to know when **persistent** QThread threads have completed a **round** of work.  By persistent I mean that the QThreads don't die after completing some work.

I am using persistent threads with this threading style.

```
class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public slots:
    void doWork() {
        /* ... */
    }
};

QThread *threadA = new QThread;
QThread *threadB = new QThread;
Worker *workerA = new Worker;
Worker *workerB = new Worker;
workerA->moveToThread(threadA);
workerB->moveToThread(threadB);
threadA->start();
threadB->start();
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(workerA, "doWork", Qt::QueuedConnection);
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(workerB, "doWork", Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

**I have a scenario as such:**

```
//Outside force (OS/driver) calls this very frequently.
//Gets called a lot so want to re-use threads instead of creating new 
//threads each time.
C callback function(some parameters)  
{  
   //STEP 1
   //Feed 2 threads with computational expensive work.
   //threads should be pre-made threads to save time on thread creation.
   //do not terminate threads because they will be re-used next time C callback
   //function
   //is called with a new round of work.

    //STEP 2
    //Need to pause/wait/BLOCK function execution here until the 2 worker threads
    //have completed the work.
    //THIS IS THE PROBLEM! No efficient way to block! I don't see how a signal/slot
    //can be used for this purpose.

    //STEP3  
    //After 2 threads complete their assigned work, resume execution of this C
    //callback function.  
    //Perform some non-threaded work in this function to complete the job.

    //return (end function execution), all work for this round/call is complete.
}
```

The problem is that with **PERSISTENT** threads there is no way to block as explained in the above pseudo code.

I can't call QThread::wait() because that can only be used for blocking until work is completed in a NON-PERSISTENT THREADS scenario.  wait() waits until threads die... making it useless for my needs.  For me, wait() just waits forever because my threads don't die.

I don't think that a signal slot thing can be used for blocking, at least I don't see how.  Maybe there is some non-obvious event trick. I realize that I could have a busy wile loop checking some flags that are manipulated by the worker threads but this steels CPU time away from the threads.

If you know of an efficient way to block with persistent QThread threads, I would really appreciate a code sample of how this can be done.

Comment: I think QWaitCondition is your friend.

Comment: Or return to the event loop instead of blocking and send a signal from the thread which finished to trigger the continuation in the waiting thread (in a slot).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `QSemaphore` with a counter at 0 before the calls to `doWork`, the main thread waits with `semaphore.acquire(2);` and each worker calls `semaphore.release(1);` when the work is done.
So, the main thread wakes up only when the 2 workers are done.

---

You can add a slot that does nothing in your `Worker` objects, that you call after starting the work:

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(workerA, "doWork", Qt::QueuedConnection);
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(workerB, "doWork", Qt::QueuedConnection);

QMetaObject::invokeMethod(workerA, "doNothing", Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection;
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(workerB, "doNothing", Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection);
```

The `Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection` means that `invokeMethod` will block until it can actually call the slot `doNothing()` and return.

---

You can run a `QEventLoop` and make it quit when it receives a signal:

```
QEventLoop loop;
// the connection have to be made before running the tasks
// to avoid race condition in case the task is very short
loop.connect(workerA, SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
loop.connect(workerB, SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));

QMetaObject::invokeMethod(workerA, "doWork", Qt::QueuedConnection);
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(workerB, "doWork", Qt::QueuedConnection);

// the loop will be interrupted once for each worker   
for(int i=0; i < 2; ++i) {
    loop.exec();
}
```